# Convert multiple PPTX files to PDF at once using R

Tags: r

I have several powerpoint pptx files in my folder that I want to convert to PDF.

I found the code below that is supposed to be used to convert PowerPoint to pdf. I'm not sure how to used it for mutiple files.

```
pdf <- convert_to_pdf(path, pdf_file = tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"))
```

Any suggestions on how to do that with R?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you familiar with loops in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_files <- list.files() # Get all the files in your working directory
pptx_files <- all_files[ which(stringr::str_detect(all_files, "\\.pptx"))] # filter for only those files with .pptx extenstion

# Loop through all the pptx files converting them to pdf using the function. Replace the .pptx extension with a .pdf
for(i in seq_along(pptx_files)) {
  convert_to_pdf(path = pptx_files[i], pdf_file = paste0(str_remove(pptx_files[i], "\\.pptx"), ".pdf"))
}
```